# How to train with samples of unequal length by multiple graphics cards in Pytorch？

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, time-series, multiprocessing

I have some samples, their shapes are like (128, 36), (64, 36), (77, 36), ... like this, they are some time series of unequal length.
My neural network only include nn.LSTM and nn.Linear, and I'm sure it can handle time series samples of varying lengths.
I have multiple graphics cards. How can I write code so that each graphics card can train with different single samples at the same time?

I found that I could only create a dataloader whose batch_size is 1 and then use a single graphics card for training, even if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1. This is too slow.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to train a model on samples of unequal lengths, but when you have multiple GPUs in PyTorch, you might want to consider these methodologies:

Custom data loader
You could write a customized data loader, that returns only one sequence each time. Setting batch_size to 1, will make sure every iteration from the data loader will just give you a single sequence.

Data Parallelisms
Utilizing DataParallel or maybe DistributedDataParallel, allows you the distribute workload across multiple GPUs. Since you want to process each sequence in an individual way, you need to make sure every sequence goes to different GPUs for processing it.

Manual Allocations to GPUs
Another way, manually you could allocate each samples to different GPUs. Thereafter, you collect the results back.

Let me elaborate more, but in a simple example:

Definition of the Model:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class SimpleModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim):
        super(SimpleModel, self).__init__()
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_dim, hidden_dim, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)

    def forward(self, x):
        h_0 = torch.zeros(1, x.size(0), hidden_dim).cuda(x.device.index)
        c_0 = torch.zeros(1, x.size(0), hidden_dim).cuda(x.device.index)
        out, _ = self.lstm(x, (h_0, c_0))
        out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])
        return out
```

Simulation of Your Data:

```
# Assume you have 2 GPUs
num_gpus = 4
data_on_gpus = []

# Generate some data with variable sequence lengths
for _ in range(num_gpus):
    seq_len = torch.randint(60, 130, (1,)).item()
    data = torch.randn(1, seq_len, 36).cuda(_)
    data_on_gpus.append(data)
```

Loop for Training:

```
input_dim = 36
hidden_dim = 50
output_dim = 10

# Initialize the models on each GPU
models = [SimpleModel(input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim).cuda(i) for i in range(num_gpus)]

# Initialize the optimizers
optimizers = [torch.optim.Adam(models[i].parameters()) for i in range(num_gpus)]

# Loop for training
for epoch in range(10):
    for i in range(num_gpus):
        optimizers[i].zero_grad()
        data = data_on_gpus[i]
        model = models[i]
        output = model(data)
        loss = torch.mean(output)
        loss.backward()
        optimizers[i].step()
```